# Android: How to improve speed of onMeasure()

Tags: java, android, performance, android-recyclerview

I'm doing an app where I have a RecyclerView(https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) with hundreds of elements and Log prints this:

```
2022-02-23 17:01:21.340 D/RecyclerViewAdapterUpdateExpandable: >>Toggle Tag Tutte le carte
2022-02-23 17:01:21.992 D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this =androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{51f7538 VFED..... .F....ID 0,99-720,1257 #7f0a017e app:id/recycler_view_list}time =627 ms
2022-02-23 17:01:21.992 D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this =androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{342a04c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1258}time =628 ms
2022-02-23 17:01:21.993 D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this =androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{e45720f V.E...... ......ID 0,-1-720,1257 #7f0a00cd app:id/fragment_container}time =629 ms
2022-02-23 17:01:21.996 D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this =androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{c686b6e V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1353}time =632 ms
2022-02-23 17:01:21.996 D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this =androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout{1a3af70 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1353 #1020002 android:id/content}time =632 ms
2022-02-23 17:01:21.996 D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this =androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout{25104ed V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1353 #7f0a0037 app:id/action_bar_root}time =632 ms
2022-02-23 17:01:21.996 D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this =android.widget.FrameLayout{7092eb1 V.E...... ......ID 0,91-720,1444}time =632 ms
2022-02-23 17:01:21.996 D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this =android.widget.LinearLayout{9d3323b V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1444}time =632 ms
2022-02-23 17:01:21.997 D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this =DecorView@1af831f[MainActivity]time =632 ms
2022-02-23 17:01:22.045 I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Are there any common practices to improve the performance?
I've tried to empty constructor of the ViewHolder and onBind() methods but the time is about the same, so I think the time depends only on the number of items.

Comment: If onMeasure is creating ViewHolders and calling onBind, that itself is probably a problem.  Especially if it's doing it for every item, that's a complete violation of how a recycler view should work (if an item isn't on screen it shouldn't even be fetched, much less bound).

Comment: So the problem is that the Recycler of the library I'm using is not good? I never call onMeasure() in my code.

Comment: onMeasure is called whenever a view is resized (including the first time it's sized) and is called by the system.